# "EMMA: nothing to do: no metadata found in any of the data files" while creating coverage.html in android with Emma

Tags: android, code-coverage, emma

I have created coverage.ec file in android emulator and able to view the file, but not able to read the conents.According to my knowledge, we can see the coverage only after generating coverage.html file. For generating this I have gone through [Building an Android app and test project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+an+Android+app+and+test+project) and  [CoverageTestHowTo](http://code.google.com/p/android-crawler/wiki/CoverageTestHowTo)  . But with out coverage.em file I am not able to create coverage.html file. Is there any other way to generate coverage.html ? or help me to generate coverage.em file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done everything correctly just run following command:

```
java -cp external/emma/lib/emma.jar emma report -r html -in coverage.ec -sp <path-to-src-of-project-under-test> -in out/target/common/obj/APPS/<yourproject_intermediates>/coverage.em
```

html file will be generated in coverage folder of AOSP root directory.

Comment: Hi Mandar, Thanks for sharing your thoughts with me. I have generated coverage.html file, coverage.em, coverage.ec, coverage.txt, coverage.html, _files.html etc.. with emma in android test project. Now I am trying to integrate these with Hudson. Could you please help me out for obtaining this?. I have configured the paths in surefire as well as in artifacts but the code coverage is null.

Comment: Sorry Manesh, but i am not familiar about integration with Hudson.